# ShapeSource images is not loading in Android using @rnmapbox

Tags: android, react-native

ShapeSource images is not loading in Android using @rnmapbox.

```
      <MapboxGL.MapView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        styleURL={
          this.state.customMapStyle === "" || this.state.customMapStyle === " "
            ? MapboxGL.StyleURL.Satellite
            : this.state.customMapStyle
        }
        logoEnabled={false}
        onDidFinishLoadingMap={this.onDidFinishLoadingStyle}
        scaleBarEnabled={false}
        attributionEnabled={false}
      >
        <MapboxGL.Camera
          container="map"
          zoomLevel={this.state.mapZoomLevel}
          maxBounds={
            Object.keys(this.state.bounds).length === 0
              ? undefined
              : this.state.bounds
          }
          styleURL={
            this.state.customMapStyle === "" ||
            this.state.customMapStyle === " "
              ? MapboxGL.StyleURL.Satellite
              : this.state.customMapStyle
          }
          animationMode="moveTo"
          centerCoordinate={this.state.coords}
        />
        {this.state.mapBoxsource && this.state.mapBoxsource.length > 0 && (
          <MapboxGL.Images
            images={this.state.images}
            onImageMissing={url => {
              this.setState({
                images: {
                  ...this.state.images,
                  [url]: { uri: url },
                },
              });
            }}
          />
        )}
        {this.state.mapBoxsource && this.state.mapBoxsource.length > 0 && (
          <MapboxGL.ShapeSource
            id={"allLightMarkers"}
            shape={{
              type: "FeatureCollection",
              features: this.state.mapBoxsource,
            }}
            onPress={e => {
              this.navigateAssetdetailScreen(e);
            }}
          >
            <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
              id="markersLevel1"
              style={{
                iconImage: ["get", "markerImage"],
                iconSize: 1.0,
                iconAllowOverlap: true,
              }}
            />
          </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
        )}
      </MapboxGL.MapView>
```

If I given  URL in shapsoure images I want to load in android also.

Comment: Comment from Mykyta: please add more details to this question. Thank you! It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.